# java 8 lambda toMap showing type cast error

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I am getting type cast error when trying to collect the list of objects to Map using lambda expression java 8

here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
List<Player> players = Arrays.asList(
        new Player("Liz", Gender.FEMALE, 20),
        new Player("Liz", Gender.FEMALE, 22),
        new Player("Bob", Gender.MALE, 20)          
        );

System.out.println(
        players.stream()
                 .collect(toMap(
                         player -> player.getName()+"_"+player.getAge(), 
// above line giving error. 
//The method getAge() is undefined for the type Object
//- The method getName() is undefined for the type Object                                
                         player -> player))
        );

}
```

once I type cast it to (Player) like below, it works fine. any idea why compiler asking for type cast?

```
player -> ((Player) player).getName()+"_"+((Player) player).getAge()
```

Player class is as below:

```
class Player {

private String name;
private Integer age;
private Gender gender;

public Player(String name, Gender gender, Integer age){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}
// ...... with corresponding getters and setters    
}
```

Comment: Works fine on JDK 1.8.0_65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been an issue in certain versions (I want to say 1.8.0_45, but I can't confirm).  I just tried your code on 1.8.0_71 and it works for me.

The latest version is 1.8.0_111, so you should try upgrading to that.

Comment: thanks for the input. yes, it worked on command prompt with 1.8.0_111. eclipse still shows error, need to check the eclipse settings.